# Is it better for me to keep an old referee's contact details if i have been unable to confirm them?

Tags: resume

When i was made redundant from my old job my employer (that being the man who hired me, not the company that brought the company then shut our department down) agreed to become my referee for my resume telling me, for atleast the next 6 months the details would be correct. this included his mobile and work email address.

6 months after and quitting my previous job i went to try and confirm his details as a few months prior the location the department i worked in was shut down for good meaning anyone in the same department as me would have moved on by now but i have no idea if my old employer just has a new position in the company or if he went somewhere else. i tried to call him on his mobile and i still get his message bank but after numerous repeated attempts to get in contact with him i have gotten no replies.

I have been told that it looks bad on my resume if i have less that 2 referees. the only other referee i have is a Lecturer i had from University. is it better for me to keep my old employer's details on the resume with only his mobile number seemingly valid or would it hurt my chances more by an employer calling his mobile and only ever getting his message box and no replies?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see as how you have much choice. If you have a written reference from him, that is often sufficient, in the absence of anything else.

At least if they ring him they'll see it's actually a valid number. Not ideal, but better than nothing at all.